# Permission BLUETOOTH for Android 13 in kivy app

Tags: python, android, bluetooth, kivy, pyjnius

I am a beginner Kivy user. I made an app that displays Arduino data on mobile via Bluetooth. I allow access in buildozer.spec as follows:

```
android.permissions = BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,BLUETOOTH
```

The app worked well ,but now it can't run on my android. I get an error like below:

```
JVM exception occurred : Need android.permission BLUETOOTH CONNECT permission for AttributionSource ( uid - 10316 packageName org test.myapp , attribution Tag- null , token android.os.BinderProxy@df550d7 , next null ) : Adapter Service getBondedDevices java.lang.securityException
```

How do I fix this error?

My app works fine on Android 11 and below but it doesn't work on my mobile which its Android is 13.
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your main.py program:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission 
request_permissions([Permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,Permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN ])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In android 12 above You need to ask from the user
`BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` permission both.
under android 12 you need to ask `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this permission doesn't work either.